# How to replace a Html Tag?

Tags: javascript

Please check my code:

```
<div id="seconds">
  <a onclick="ChangeRefreshSeconds(15,this);" href="javascript:;">15</a>
  <b><span style="background-color:yellow;">30</span></b>
  <a onclick="ChangeRefreshSeconds(60,this);" href="javascript:;">60</a>
  <a onclick="ChangeRefreshSeconds(120,this);" href="javascript:;">120</a>
</div>
```

My current number is 30 When i click on the number `60` it should be-

```
<div id="seconds">
  <a onclick="ChangeRefreshSeconds(15,this);" href="javascript:;">15</a>
  <a onclick="ChangeRefreshSeconds(30,this);" href="javascript:;">30</a>
  <b><span style="background-color:yellow;">60</span></b>
  <a onclick="ChangeRefreshSeconds(120,this);" href="javascript:;">120</a>
</div>
```

Javascript:

```
<script>
function ChangeRefreshSeconds(s,t){
    //t.innerHTML='<span style="background-color:yellow;">'+s+'</span>';
    var textnode=document.createTextNode('<span style="background-color:yellow;">'+s+'</span>');
    t.replaceChild(textnode,t);
}
</script>
```

I am sure that i have written my JavaScript code in the wrong way.

Please solve my above code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Something like this would be a lot easier with [jQuery](http://jquery.com), if you have the possibility to use it, i would definitely advise you to.

As far as i can see your code only changes to `<span>` and doesn't change the already changed `<span's>` back to `<a>`. I assumed that's what you wanted? The piece of code for this script (in jQuery) would look something like:

```
$("div#seconds a").click(function(){
    var originalValue = $(this).html();
    var spanValue = $("b span", $(this).parent()).html();

    $("b", $(this).parent()).replaceWith('<a href="javascript:;">'+spanValue+'</a>');
    $(this).replaceWith('<b><span style="background-color:yellow;">'+originalValue+'</span></b>');
});
```

Answer (score 1):

You can replace tags for sure. But you don't have to do that. It's much simple and less obtrusive to go with just CSS approach. With CSS when you have class `active` you have great deal of flexibility to style currently selected item whatever you want.

```js
function ChangeRefreshSeconds(seconds, obj) {

    // do nothing if it's already active
    if (obj.className === 'active') return;

    var a = document.getElementById('seconds').children;
    for (var i = 0; i < a.length; i++) {
        a[i].className = '';
    }
    obj.className = 'active';

    // do something else
    alert('Current seconds: ' + seconds);
}
```

```css
#seconds .active,
#seconds .active:active {
    background: yellow;
    cursor: default;
    color: #333;
    font-weight: bold;
}
```

```html
<div id="seconds">
    <a onclick="ChangeRefreshSeconds(15, this);" href="javascript:;">15</a>
    <a onclick="ChangeRefreshSeconds(30, this);" href="javascript:;" class="active">30</a>
    <a onclick="ChangeRefreshSeconds(60, this);" href="javascript:;">60</a>
    <a onclick="ChangeRefreshSeconds(120, this);" href="javascript:;">120</a>
</div>
```

Comment: I don't need to change my html. Because this html is being used by maximum number of pages. so i want to changes only my JavaScript.

Comment: You don't really need to change HTML for this approach. Just `ChangeRefreshSeconds` function.

Comment: Your code is working fine. But after clicking of `60` this place should be like `<b><span style="background-color:yellow;">60</span></b>`

Answer (score 0):

try this:

```
<script>
    function ChangeRefreshSeconds(s,t){
        var textnode=document.createTextNode('<span style="backgroundcolor:yellow;">'+s+'</span>');
        t.parentNode.replaceChild(textnode,t);
     }
 </script>
```

Answer (score 0):

Following is my approach, try out this

```js
function ChangeRefreshSeconds(event){
    event = event || window.event;
    var seconds = document.getElementById('seconds');
    var anchors = seconds.getElementsByTagName('a');
    
    var i;
    for (i = 0; i < anchors.length; i++) {
        anchors[i].className = '';
    }
   
    event.target.className = 'active';
}
```

```css
.active {
    background-color:yellow;
}
```

```html
<div id="seconds">
  <a onclick="ChangeRefreshSeconds(event);" href="javascript:;">15</a>
  <a onclick="ChangeRefreshSeconds(event);" href="javascript:;">30</a>
  <a onclick="ChangeRefreshSeconds(event);" href="javascript:;">60</a>
  <a onclick="ChangeRefreshSeconds(event);" href="javascript:;">120</a>
</div>
```